# Deploy Rails spree to Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed rails spree app to AWS Beanstalk successfully. Then I added some new products together with their images. The app by default saves the images in my_app/public/spree/products folder. Every thing went fine until I deployed new code. The new code is deployed successfully but the "products" folder is gone. I now have to re-upload all of my images manually. Anyone has any idea what is going here?

Please let me know if you need any further info.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Application will contain a public folder and under of this, we have spree products/taxons images folder...Those files are static by nature, so it’s a good idea to serve them using S3 because for every deployment our code replace.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic beanstalk servers are somehow out of your control, meaning AWS controls when they are restarted and even terminated and rebuilt. Therefore, you shouldn't store anything on local disks (which is what Spree does by default).
The solution to your problem is simply to [store them on S3](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/s3_storage.html) as described here.